# What is the current state of zkEVM development?

Tags: solidity, dapps, evm, layer-2, zero-knowledge

What is the current state of zkEVM? That is - a **general-purpose** (not specialized like Loopring or Immutable), EVM-compatible, Solidity-compatible zk-rollup layer 2. To my knowledge they are still being developed and none are live, but is that true? Is there a resource or a running list out there that details the current progress towards zkEVM?

To my knowledge, these are the current options:

- Starknet: not actually EVM-compatible
- zkSync 2.0: not actually EVM-compatible, solidity code compiles to another language
- Scroll: in development, doesn't seem very official and is not backed by big names
- Taiko: partnered with Loopring, in early stages of development
- Hermez 2.0: Polygon's zkEVM, still in development

Am I missing some? Am I incorrect about the ones I've listed? Is there a comprehensive list out there detailing the current progress towards zkEVM?

Answer (score 0):

A zkEVM is an EVM-compatible virtual machine that supports zero-knowledge proof computation. Unlike regular virtual machines, a zkEVM proves the correctness of program execution, including the validity of inputs and outputs used in the operation. In a June Twitter thread, Scroll’s Luozhu Zhang described three different types of zkEVMs: bytecode level, language level and consensus level. Vitalik has shared his perspectives on zkEVMs in detail in his blog. It can be briefly understood from the following diagram published in his [blog](https://vitalik.ca/general/2022/08/04/zkevm.html).

[image]

Polygon has launched its zkEVM TestNet recently. DeFI platforms Uniswap and Aave have be joinined the zkEVM testing network. Following are the major components of Polygon implementation of zkEVM.

- Proof of Efficiency (PoE) consensus mechanism.
- zkNode software including a synchronizer, sequencer and aggregator.
- LX-to-LY bridge.
- zkProver.